# Share a repetitive function between forms

Tags: c#

This is my first question. I'm a complete newbie (I have some Arduino and Delphi knowledge, but nothing on C#) and there's something I've been attempting without success. In order to optimize some code I received I found some functions copypasted on each form and I would liek to reduce them to one (and better if in a separate .cs file), and access it from different forms.

For example: I have labels on Form1 and Form2, whose colour I want to be changed based on the .Checked property of a CheckBox on each Form. It's obvious cb_colorear finds controls in Form1. I tried to pass it values like (String formName) and then tried formName.Controls.Find but that didn't work. Any tips?
I'd also love to be pointed to some documentation on these matter. I've tried searching a bit, but without knowing C# and english not being fluent on English I'm struggling to find info I understand. Thank you all for your help.

```
//Form1 Code    
namespace PruebaAccesoMetodos
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show(); ;
        }

        public Color cb_colorear(String cbName, String label)
        {

            Control[] ctrl = Controls.Find(cbName, true);
            CheckBox cb = ctrl[0] as CheckBox;

            Control[] ctrl2 = Controls.Find(label, true);
            Label lbl = ctrl2[0] as Label;

            if (cb.Checked == false)
            {
                return Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                return Color.LawnGreen;
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

               label1.BackColor = cb_colorear(checkBox1.Name, label1.Name);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\");
        }
    }
}
```

And Form2 code:

```
namespace PruebaAccesoMetodos
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form1 frm1instance = new Form1();
            label1.BackColor = frm1instance.cb_colorear(this.checkBox1.Name, this.label1.Name);


        }

    }
}
```

Update:

Ok, I made it work. Should've tried a bit more before asking haha.

Changed the cb_colorear function to receive Form type values:

```
    public Color cb_colorear(String cbName, String label, Form formName)
    {

        Control[] ctrl = formName.Controls.Find(cbName, true);
        CheckBox cb = ctrl[0] as CheckBox;

        Control[] ctrl2 = formName.Controls.Find(label, true);
        Label lbl = ctrl2[0] as Label;

        if (cb.Checked == false)
        {
            return Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            return Color.LawnGreen;
        }

    }
```

Then added a this to each button calling the function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       label1.BackColor = cb_colorear(checkBox1.Name, label1.Name, this);
}
```

But, while it works, is this the propper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void cb_colorear(this Form form, string cbName, string label)
    {
        Control[] ctrl = form.Controls.Find(cbName, true);
        CheckBox cb = ctrl[0] as CheckBox;

        Control[] ctrl2 = form.Controls.Find(label, true);
        Label lbl = ctrl2[0] as Label;

        if (!cb.Checked)
        {
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
        }
    }
}
```

So what have we done here:

1. We create a new static class (I chose to call it `Extensions` for the example).
2. We create our extension method. This method has to be static. Notice the first argument (`this Form form` instead of just `Form form`). This single keyword makes all the difference. It is what turns our normal method to an extension.
3. The rest is the same as your code. We use `form` as we would any other arguments. There is no need to `return` the `Color`, as we can set the label's `BackColor` property directly.

With the extension method declared, we can do the following in *any* form:

```
private void SomeFormMethod()
{
    this.cb_colorear(checkBox.Name, label.Name)
}
```

The first argument is passed to the extension method implicitly, allowing us to use the `this.method()` syntax.

Comment: I think you have an error there. Shouldn't it be public static void cb_colorear instead of public static color?
It worked for me that way. Thank you!